# Uploading Zip to Phonegap Using PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, cordova

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to have a one click solution to uploading and building my mobile application.  I have successfully done this using cURL but was trying to use native PowerShell commands instead.  In cURL I can use the -F (--form) parameter and pass the zip file (e.g. -F file=@C:...\www.zip).  I cannot figure out how to achieve this same thing using PowerShell.  I am trying to use Invoke-RestMethod but not sure if this is correct.  Here's a link to the PhoneGap API:
 https://build.phonegap.com/docs/write_api

Any help would much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps/:id -Headers @{Authorization='Basic username-and-password-in-base64'} -Method Put -InFile "www.zip"
```

username-and-password-in-base64 is your Adobe/PhoneGap Build username and password combined into a string "username:password" and encoded using Base64 (http://www.base64decode.org/).

:id in the url is your app id in phonegap build.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$pathToZip = "bin/phonegap.zip"
$user = "user"
$pass = "password"

## convert to secure password since we can't use get-credential in non interactive mode
$securepass = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force

## create a PSCredential object
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user, $securepass)

$appId = "12345"
$url = "https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps/" + $appId;

Write-Host $url

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Credential $credential -Method Put -InFile $pathToZip
```

Comment: Same problem, i get a 500 error code when using the above method.